# How can I unpack two values from user defined class?

Tags: python, oop

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
```

How can I get two variables `x,y=Vector(20,10)`?

Answer should be x=20, y=10.

Comment: You are missing a `self` as the first argument to any class method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to access the `x` and `y` attribute, you can access them using the dot notation:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
vector = Vector(10, 20)
x = vector.x
y = vector.y

print('x =', x)
print('y =', y)
```

```
# Output
x = 10
y = 20
```

If you want to give your class a behavior similar to tuple unpacking, you can override `__iter__`:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iter__(self):
       yield self.x
       yield self.y

    def __str__(self):
        return 'x={}, y={}'.format(self.x, self.y)

vector = Vector(x=10, y=20)
print(vector)

x, y = vector
print('x =', x)
print('y =', y)
```

```
# Output
x=10, y=20
x = 10
y = 20
```

Comment: Thanks, A lot, I exactly wanted this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__` method is currently defined incorrectly; the signature should be `def __init__(self, x, y)`, where the important thing to note is that the first parameter is `self`.

Without defining some method to return the `x` and `y` values as a tuple, you wouldn't be able to extract them as `x, y = Vector(10, 20)`, you would need to access the instance attributes separately, i.e.:

```
vector = Vector(10, 20)
x = vector.x
y = vector.y
```

Alternatively, you could define an extra method on the class to return a tuple and unpack that:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def coords(self):
        return self.x, self.y

vector = Vector(10, 20)
x, y = vector.coords()
print(x, y)
```

Output:

```
10 20
```